# A Word A Day for Korean

Tags: word-usage

Does anyone know of any Korean service that sends or publishes a regular A Word A Day for native Korean speakers to expand their own vocabulary? I'm having trouble finding one, even though these are really easy to find for English (e.g. Merriam-Webster, Oxford English Dictionary).

Comment: https://www.transparent.com/word-of-the-day/today/korean.html, https://www.koreanclass101.com/korean-phrases/, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paytopwn.koreanword&hl=en_US, apparently many more on google https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=word+of+the+day+korean&meta=

Answer (score 2):

Naver has a quiz [on this page](https://wquiz.dict.naver.com/main.dict), and you could also check out the [home page of the Naver Korean dictionary](https://ko.dict.naver.com/), as it offers not only a section called "Today's idiom", but also FAQ's for how to use certain words correctly.

Comment: Can those "idiom of the day" or "word of the day" be sent by e-mail? (Like wordreference in english has such a feature)